# fixed and non fixed size forms in parent form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, resize, size, parent-child

I have a parrent container form with several child forms inside some of the forms have a fixed size, I have done this by changing the  max size and the min size of those forms to the exact same value. I also have child forms that have no fixed size.

Problem If have fixed-size forms and non fixed-size forms open in my parent form the forms get mudeld up.

how can I get the two types (fixed size and non fixed size forms) to coexist in the parent form?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind for me would be Anchoring the non-fixed size forms so they'll resize with the parent form.  If that's what you're trying to do.  Otherwise I'm a little unclear with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `FormBorderStyle` of your fixed forms to `FixedSingle`. Now you only need to set the `Size` of the form. `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` aren't necessary. The fixed forms won't look "muddled" this way.

Setting `MaximizeBox` to `False` will also prevent the form from maximizing, if that's required.